# Как проверить загрузилась ли страница при парсинге? Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

При обходе страницы с помощью selenium возникает исключение `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='content']"}` так как страница не загружается (смотрел в chromedriver, страница не была загружена `Не удается получить доступ к сайту`). Как можно перед началом работы проверить загрузилась ли страница и если нет, то обновить ее?

Вообще, изначально просто обрабатывал исключение через `except NoSuchElementException: print('не найдено')`, но почему-то все равно иногда создается исключение, а иногда обрабатывается правильно. Возможно, не туда прописал:

```
driver.get('адрес')
try:
    html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content']")
    ...
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('не найдено')
```

Желательно, конечно, в случае если не найдено обновлять страницу и искать по новой.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что значит `NameError`?

Comment: да, одна из переменных не определена `is not defined`. А не определена потому, что по какой-то причине страница не загрузилась, ее просто нужно обновить в таком случае и продолжить работу дальше.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда, пожалуйста, приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: *>>страница не загружается* - метод `WebDriver.get` **блокирует** процесс до тех пор, пока содержимое **ссылки** полностью не загрузится. Так что страница загружается. Возможно, содержимое, которое Вы ищете, появляется не сразу, а через какое-то время, поэтому стоит воспользоваться ожиданиями. Советую почитать [Selenium для Python. Глава 5. Ожидания](https://habr.com/ru/post/273089/). А лучше не только эту главу, а полностью весь цикл статей.

Comment: у меня стоит примитивное ожидание time.sleep(10), я смотрел на работу драйвера, и у страницы появилось `Не удается получить доступ к сайту`, если обновить эту страницу то все ок, вот нужно как-то распознать если не получилось получить доступ к сайту, то обновить.

Comment: Ну тогда просто смотрите, что загрузилось. Загрузилось без доступа - обновляете.

Comment: Вот я про это и спрашиваю)) Как посмотреть, что загрузилось без доступа? если без доступа, то обновить.

Comment: Вы же глазами это как-то видите. Так и смотреть. Например, по строке `Не удается получить доступ к сайту`. Или же по коду статуса, если не 200 - значит не ОК.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Так Вы даже явно отлавливаете это исключение. Обновляйте страницу и начинайте сначала вместо `print('не найдено')`.

Comment: То есть после `except NoSuchElementException:` прописать опять `driver.get('адрес')` `html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content']")
    ...` ? Я не пойму как правильно прописать, чтобы тот же  урл обновился и снова выполнился код и `try:` Вот в чем вопрос) И вопрос, почему если я отлавливаю конкретно это исключение иногда оно обрабатывается корректно, а иногда все равно проблема `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='content']"}`

Comment: `while True: if загрузилось_нормально: break`. *>>И вопрос, почему если я отлавливаю конкретно это исключение иногда оно обрабатывается корректно, а иногда все равно проблема* - непонятный набор слов. Сформируйте нормально вопрос.

Comment: у меня вот это `except NoSuchElementException: ` было уже прописано, но все равно вылезло `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='content']"}`